Is there any evidence of reasoning or argument in ancient texts outside Ancient Greece?
Is there any evidence of reasoning or argument in ancient texts (says before 500BC) outside Ancient Greece?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Here are some articles about Indian and Buddhist logic: reshttps://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.489008
https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.213362
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyaya
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_logico-epistemology

Ecclesiastes is my fav.


Chinese Logic

Hindu Logic

Buddhist (pramana) Logic

Jain Logic


Origins as old or older than Aristotle

And a lot less argued over.
